# How to fix awk print the same line twice in multiple condition statement?

Tags: awk

I have a log file looks like this:

```
Jun 29 16:46:13 iPhone SomeThing[MULTILINE] <Notice>: [AppName] file.x:115 DEBUG: ClassNumberOne viewControllers: (
    "<UINavigationController: 0x105031a00>",
    "<UINavigationController: 0x10505ba00>",
    "<UINavigationController: 0x10486fe00>",
    "<UINavigationController: 0x105052600>",
    "<UINavigationController: 0x105065c00>"
)
Jun 29 16:46:13 someline that should not be captured
Jun 29 16:46:13 iPhone SomeThing[SINGLE LINE] <Notice>: [AppName] file.x:151 DEBUG: ClassNumberTwo ARG2 2
Jun 29 16:46:13 someline that should not be captured
Jun 29 16:46:13 iPhone SomeThing[MULTILINE] <Notice>: [AppName] file.x:152 DEBUG: ClassNumberOne viewControllers: {
    "<UINavigationController: 0x105031a00>",
    "<UINavigationController: 0x10505ba00>",
    "<UINavigationController: 0x10486fe00>",
    "<UINavigationController: 0x105052600>",
    "<UINavigationController: 0x105065c00>"
}
Jun 29 16:46:13 someline that should not be captured
Jun 29 16:46:13 iPhone SomeThing[SINGLE LINE] <Notice>: [AppName] file.x:153 DEBUG: ClassNumberTwo ARG2 2
```

my command is to print the line that consist `DEBUG:`, be it a single line log (tagged with SINGLE LINE in the sample log for explanation purposes), or multiline (tagged with MULTILINE) that starts with `(` until `)`, or starts with `{` and ends with `}`. Below is the code:

```
awk 'f; /\}}/{f=0} /\)/{f=0} /DEBUG:/{print; f=/\{||\(/}' file.txt
```

My expected output is the same as the input (excluding non-relevant line like `Jun 29 16:46:13 someline that should not be captured`) provided on the top of this post, however I gets a duplicates for single line:

```
Jun 29 16:46:13 iPhone SomeThing[MULTILINE] <Notice>: [AppName] file.x:115 DEBUG: ClassNumberOne viewControllers: (
    "<UINavigationController: 0x105031a00>",
    "<UINavigationController: 0x10505ba00>",
    "<UINavigationController: 0x10486fe00>",
    "<UINavigationController: 0x105052600>",
    "<UINavigationController: 0x105065c00>"
)
Jun 29 16:46:13 iPhone SomeThing[SINGLE LINE] <Notice>: [AppName] file.x:151 DEBUG: ClassNumberTwo ARG2 2
Jun 29 16:46:13 iPhone SomeThing[SINGLE LINE] <Notice>: [AppName] file.x:151 DEBUG: ClassNumberTwo ARG2 2
Jun 29 16:46:13 iPhone SomeThing[MULTILINE] <Notice>: [AppName] file.x:152 DEBUG: ClassNumberOne viewControllers: {
    "<UINavigationController: 0x105031a00>",
    "<UINavigationController: 0x10505ba00>",
    "<UINavigationController: 0x10486fe00>",
    "<UINavigationController: 0x105052600>",
    "<UINavigationController: 0x105065c00>"
}
Jun 29 16:46:13 iPhone SomeThing[SINGLE LINE] <Notice>: [AppName] file.x:153 DEBUG: ClassNumberTwo ARG2 2
Jun 29 16:46:13 iPhone SomeThing[SINGLE LINE] <Notice>: [AppName] file.x:153 DEBUG: ClassNumberTwo ARG2 2
```

Any idea how to fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk 'f{print; if (/^[)}]/) f=0} /DEBUG:/{if (/[({]$/) f=1; print}' file
Jun 29 16:46:13 iPhone SomeThing[MULTILINE] <Notice>: [AppName] file.x:115 DEBUG: ClassNumberOne viewControllers: (
    "<UINavigationController: 0x105031a00>",
    "<UINavigationController: 0x10505ba00>",
    "<UINavigationController: 0x10486fe00>",
    "<UINavigationController: 0x105052600>",
    "<UINavigationController: 0x105065c00>"
)
Jun 29 16:46:13 iPhone SomeThing[SINGLE LINE] <Notice>: [AppName] file.x:151 DEBUG: ClassNumberTwo ARG2 2
Jun 29 16:46:13 iPhone SomeThing[MULTILINE] <Notice>: [AppName] file.x:152 DEBUG: ClassNumberOne viewControllers: {
    "<UINavigationController: 0x105031a00>",
    "<UINavigationController: 0x10505ba00>",
    "<UINavigationController: 0x10486fe00>",
    "<UINavigationController: 0x105052600>",
    "<UINavigationController: 0x105065c00>"
}
Jun 29 16:46:13 iPhone SomeThing[SINGLE LINE] <Notice>: [AppName] file.x:153 DEBUG: ClassNumberTwo ARG2 2
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use this `awk`:

```
awk '/DEBUG:/{print; f = /[({]$/; next}; f; /^[)}]/{f = 0}' file.log
```

```
Jun 29 16:46:13 iPhone SomeThing[MULTILINE] <Notice>: [AppName] file.x:115 DEBUG: ClassNumberOne viewControllers: (
    "<UINavigationController: 0x105031a00>",
    "<UINavigationController: 0x10505ba00>",
    "<UINavigationController: 0x10486fe00>",
    "<UINavigationController: 0x105052600>",
    "<UINavigationController: 0x105065c00>"
)
Jun 29 16:46:13 iPhone SomeThing[SINGLE LINE] <Notice>: [AppName] file.x:151 DEBUG: ClassNumberTwo ARG2 2
Jun 29 16:46:13 iPhone SomeThing[MULTILINE] <Notice>: [AppName] file.x:152 DEBUG: ClassNumberOne viewControllers: {
    "<UINavigationController: 0x105031a00>",
    "<UINavigationController: 0x10505ba00>",
    "<UINavigationController: 0x10486fe00>",
    "<UINavigationController: 0x105052600>",
    "<UINavigationController: 0x105065c00>"
}
Jun 29 16:46:13 iPhone SomeThing[SINGLE LINE] <Notice>: [AppName] file.x:153 DEBUG: ClassNumberTwo ARG2 2
```

Comment: I edited the post, and you're right, the actual log contains more dirty logs that don't contain DEBUG keyword.

Comment: ok I have updated answer based on Ed's helpful comments and your edits.